# Can't get any G+ post's resharers with g+ api

Tags: google-api, google-plus

According to this documentation https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/listByActivity
g+ api supports thing as "getting resharers of a post"
But i can't get it to work.

This is a post url - https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AseemTejpal/posts/PAcm67KwXaS it's have 22 resharers atm.

**My steps** (after authorizing and obtaining access token with scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` and 
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13hypi4rtjjx5ko404chx4pwzikebbaliw/people/resharers?access_token={my_access_token}
```

by executing above request i'm getting:

```
{
 "kind": "plus#peopleFeed",
 "etag": "\"Sh4n9u6EtD24TM0RmWv7jTXojqc/RL739Eu8qXAJMlvqfIb_fYCs2JA\"",
 "title": "Google+ People By Activity: Resharer",
 "totalItems": 0,
 "items": []
}
```

for instance, plusoners works fine

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13hypi4rtjjx5ko404chx4pwzikebbaliw/people/plusoners?access_token={my_access_token}
```

result: https://pastebin.com/5khY6cAp

What am i doing wrong? Why resharers request returns 0 results? Do G+ supports obtaining resharers by api at all? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [looks](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-plus-platform/issues/1084) like that has not worked for a while. I doubtful if Google has any plans to fix it anytime soon.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.